# webview app force closes when back key is pressed

Tags: android, webview

In my webview app i open a website for showing lways in landscape.I also added the onKeyDown function() also. But when a link is opened and back key is pressed the app is closed.please help me to solve

WebActivity.java

```
package com.example.samworkshops;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class WebActivity extends Activity {
    public WebView webview;


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webview.loadUrl("http://app.samworkshops.org");

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // Check if the key event was the Back button and if there's history
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webview.canGoBack()) {
            webview.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        // If it wasn't the Back key or there's no web page history, bubble up to the default
        // system behavior (probably exit the activity)
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
 WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
 // declared again and initialized. becomes local to onCreate
```

to

```
 webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

coz you already have

```
 public class WebActivity extends Activity {
 public WebView webview; // declared but this is never initialized
```

I guess its a `NullPointerException` leading to crash

Comment: +1 Adding to be more clear ` WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);` change this line

Answer (score 0):

Probably the onBackPressed() method is called before call `onKeyDown`

Do this. Delete your `onKeyDown` and put this one:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (webview.canGoBack()) {
                      webview.goBack();
                      return;
                  }
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two times declared `WebView`

Try this:

Replace this `WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);`
by

```
 webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

and also do this

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
       webview.goBack();

    }
```

before you will add onBackPressed() method please comment the onKeyDown method